# Combine strings of a file in java

Tags: java, string

I need to combine strings repeated in java like this:

> 1. A
> 2. A B
> 3. A B C
> 4. A B D

To have this:

> 1. A B C
> 2. A B D

The problem is that the strings is read from a file, and the file have more than 10000 lines.

Any efficient mode to resolve this?

Comment: Yes, there is. What did you try? What didn't work in what you were trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a tree structure that has a character value:

```
public class TreeNode {
     public Character value;
     public Map<Character, TreeNode> childs;
     public TreeNode() {
         childs = new HashMap<Character, TreeNode>();
     }
}
```

For each string, we will read one character at a time.
Now every time you see a "new" character, add it to root, and if it is not new, traverse through the tree to the child which is the character that has already been seen.

Once you are done with one string, you move back to the top of the tree (to the root) and do the same thing. "new" character, add to the child. If the value exist within child, move to the child.

```
// Take a list of string as an input and output combined strings as output
public List<String> Solution(List<String> input) {
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode();
    TreeNode current = root;
    for (String s : input) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            Character c = s.charAt(i);
            if (current.childs.containsKey(c)) {
                current = current.childs.get(c);
            } else {
                TreeNode child = new TreeNode();
                child.value = c;
                current.childs.put(c, child);
                current = child;
            }
        }
        current = root;
    }
    // Now our tree should be complete, do a bfs on the tree to get all unique strings.
    // Traverse the tree while constructing a string, once you reach a leaf
    // add to the list.
    return ReadStrings("", current, new ArrayList<String>());
}

public List<String> ReadStrings(String s, TreeNode current, List<String> ret) {
    s += current.value;
    if (current.childs.size() > 0) {
        for (TreeNode child : current.childs.values()) {
            ReadStrings(s, child, ret);
        }
    } else {
        // We are at a leaf, add to ret
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            ret.add(s);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Testing own code is _always_ a good idea, so stuff like `Map<char, TreeNode>` won't  happen. ... well, or that `new HashMap<TreeNode>();` ...

Comment: @JTY java.util.Map keys and values should be object, "Map" does not allow primitive data types. You should compile your code before post it.

Comment: @sedpol this java syntax... Well thanks for pointing it out and sorry for that. Just saw the question and found it interesting, wrote out what I had in my head from my smartphone. I'll make sure I take it into consideration next time